# Cálculo correcto de procentajes en java

Tags: java

Hace unos días un usuario de la comunidad realizaba ésta pregunta, y una vez se la contesté, decidió eliminarla.

Como me había llevado algún tiempo el confeccionar la respuesta para que el código funcionara, me tomo la libertad de volver a publicar la pregunta y mi respuesta.

La pregunta era la siguiente:

Buen día. Por favor alguien me podría ayudar con este error, tengo que sacar un porcentaje respecto a un rango de números. El conteo lo saco correctamente, pero no me funciona la aritmética para sacar el porcentaje.

```
public class Ej08 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       int n;
       int suma=0;
       int bajo=0;
       int inv=0;
       float num;
       double mbajo= 5.0;
       float mybajo= 14;
       double minv= 80.0;
       float myinv= 100;
       int i;
       java.util.Scanner lea = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.print("Indique la cantidad de numeros : ");
       n = lea.nextInt();
       if(n<=0)
           System.out.println("El valor no es valido");
       else {
           for(i=1;i<=n;i++) {
               System.out.print("Dato "+i+" : ");
               num=lea.nextFloat();
               suma += num;
               if(num> mbajo && num<=mybajo){
                   bajo= bajo + 1;
                   System.out.println(" sumo "+ num);

               }
               if(num> minv && num <= myinv){
                   inv= inv + 1;
                   System.out.println(" sumo "+ num);
                
               }
           }
           System.out.println("bajo trae: "+bajo);
           System.out.println("inviable tre: "+inv);
           System.out.println("n trae: "+n);
           double prom= (suma/(n*1.0));
           float pb=(bajo /n)*100;
           float pi=(inv / n)*100;
        
           /* if (prom>=01){
               5.1 7 25 70 50 90
           }*/
        
           System.out.println("El promedio de los números es : "+prom);
           System.out.println("bajo: "+pb);
           System.out.println("inviable: "+pi);
       }
       lea.close();
```

En el código se puede ver que la variable bajo trae 2 y la variable inv trae 1 y la variable n trae 6 que es el numero de veces que lee el programa.

Necesito saber cuanto es bajo de n es decir cuanto es 2 de 6 es sencillo, se divide y se multiplica por 100, pero no realiza la operación pues al final pb y pi tienen 0.0 como resultado

Comment: Hola!, lo siento por el comentario, puedes entrar al [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128316/holas)? Quiero hablar de algo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ver si me enteré de lo que necesitas y te contsto bien

Los números bajos, son los que están entre 6 y 14

Los números inviables, los que están entre 81 y 100

Cada vez que entra un número por teclado que quede entre los parámetros anteriores, incrementas sus respectivos contadores.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    //declaramos las variables de enteros
    int n, suma = 0, bajo = 0, inv = 0;
    //el resto de variables como las tienes declaradas
    float num;
    double mbajo = 5.0;
    float mybajo = 14;
    double minv = 80.0;
    float myinv = 100;
    //instalaciones la clase escaner
    java.util.Scanner lea = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
    //pedimos la cantadiad de números por consola
    System.out.print("Indique la cantidad de numeros : ");
    //recogemos los números en la variable n
    n = lea.nextInt();
    //si n menor o igual a 0
    if (n <= 0)
        //informamos de la invalidez del número
        System.out.println("El valor no es valido");
    //si es válido
    else {
        //declaramos un bucle limitado por el número de números dado
        for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            //vamos pidiendo los números
            System.out.print("Dato " + i + " : ");
            //guardamos el número dado en la variable num decimal
            num = lea.nextFloat();
            //acumulamos la suma de los números que se van dando en la variable suma
            suma += num;
            //si el número está por encima del mínimo bajo y es igual o está por debajo del máximo mínimo
            if(num > mbajo && num <= mybajo){
                //sumamos 1 a bajo
                bajo += 1;
                //System.out.println(" sumo " + num);
            }
            //si num está por encima del mínimo inviable o es igual o está por debajo del máximo inviable
            if(num > minv && num <= myinv){
                //sumamos uno al la variable inviable
                inv += 1;
                //System.out.println(" sumo " + num);
            
            }
        }
        //mostramos los resultados de bajo, inv y n
        System.out.println("bajo trae: " + bajo);
        System.out.println("inviable trae: " + inv);
        System.out.println("n trae: " + n);
    
        //hayamos los porcentajes de los promedios
        double prom = (suma / n);
        float pb = (bajo * 100) / n;
        float pi = (inv * 100) / n;
    
       /* if (prom>=01){
            5.1 7 25 70 50 90
        }*/
    
        //mostramos el resultado de los promedios
        System.out.println("El promedio de los números es : " + prom);
        System.out.println("bajo: " + pb);
        System.out.println("inviable: " + pi);
    }
    //derramos el teclado
    lea.close();
}
```